# vernemq auth using webhoooks

Tags: ssl, mqtt, mqtt-vernemq

I wants to authenticate/authorize clients on vernemq broker. This are two hooks I'm interested in:

> **auth_on_register** 
>   **auth_on_subscribe**

I have setup above hooks and endpoints for them. On new register and subscription, I'm able to log the POST request params.

[Related vernemq docs can be found here](https://vernemq.com/docs/plugindevelopment/webhookplugins.html)

**Question:**

Can we pass some custom variables in client request, so that we can handle auth.

If not, then can ssl be good alternative here, please include procedure for that?

**Details:**
by enabling auth_on_register we can get POST request to corresponding endpoint, with params:

```
{
    "peer_addr": "127.0.0.1",
    "peer_port": 8888,
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "mountpoint": "",
    "client_id": "clientid",
    "clean_session": false
}
```

you can see that it is using username and password for auth purpose, do vernemq or mqqt in general provide facility to send custom params e.g. auth_token?

I have read that we can configure ssl certificates also, so if there's no facility for custom params then I would to go with this, or any other suggestion?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking here, especially the second half of the question. Please add more context.

Comment: @hardillb I have mentioned details in edited version. Let me know if you can help me here.

Comment: Often either the username or password has been used to encode extra authentication information. With MQTT 5 you can use the new authentication mechanisms (AUTH) packets - which VerneMQ also supports as webhooks.